# How to align controls each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to align html controls next to each other without giving huge space and I try to override the bootstrap .css but no luck.

here is my screen looks like:

[image]

I have created JSFiddle and also below is my html code.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vd1Lzzpm/1/)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group1">
      <label class="col-xs-5 control-label" for="">Rows per page:</label>

      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <form action="/SystemAdmin" id="form_header_pager" method="post" name=
        "form_header_pager">
          <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number=
          "The field PageSize must be a number." data-val-required=
          "The PageSize field is required." id="PageSize" name=
          "PageSizeSelect">
            <option selected="selected" value="10">
              10
            </option>

            <option value="25">
              25
            </option>

            <option value="50">
              50
            </option>

            <option value="ALL">
              ALL
            </option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div>
      <div>
        <b>Total records:</b> 0
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group1">
      <label class="col-xs-5 control-label" for="">Show Records:</label>

      <div class="col-xs-7">
        <form action="/SystemAdmin" id="form_header_show_records" method="post"
        name="form_header_show_records">
          <select class="form-control" id="ShowRecords" name="showrecords">
            <option value="all">
              Show All Records
            </option>

            <option value="invalid">
              Show Invalid Records
            </option>

            <option value="valid">
              Show Valid Records
            </option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big spaces within your layout are caused from using the grid column widths. **Bootstrap** provides [inline form element styling](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) and it's recommended to use that instead of the grid columns.

The additional CSS adjustment I had to make was your totals area. Since it didn't have an input or select element, the vertical alignment was slightly off. If you had a row of inputs (as show in Bootstrap's documentation), you wouldn't need any additional CSS here.

You can view this corrected code snippet below. *Please note that you must run it in "Full Page" mode to view it correctly. By default the `form-inline` tool only works in viewports greater than 768px.*

```css
.record-results {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <form action="/SystemAdmin" id="form_header_pager" method="post" name="form_header_pager">
            <label for="PageSize">Rows per page:</label>
            <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field PageSize must be a number." data-val-required="The PageSize field is required." id="PageSize" name="PageSizeSelect">
                <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="50">50</option>
                <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <span class="record-results"><strong>Total records:</strong> 0</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form action="/SystemAdmin" id="form_header_show_records" method="post" name="form_header_show_records">
            <label for="showrecords">Show Records:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="ShowRecords" name="showrecords">
                <option value="all">Show All Records</option>
                <option value="invalid">Show Invalid Records</option>
                <option value="valid">Show Valid Records</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/yuxiqu/1/edit)

your layout is confused me. So I did another to achieve.
The key code:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Rows per page:</label>
    <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">test</option>
      <option value="1">test</option>
      <option value="1">test</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Total records:</label>
    <span class="text-danger">99</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Show Records:</label>
    <select name="" id="" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">test</option>
      <option value="1">test</option>
      <option value="1">test</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```